# Different results for model comparison using ANOVA function for REML and ML

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, lme4-nlme

I got this interesting results when I use `anova` test to compare two nested models. I fitted two nested mixed effects models with `lme4` package with `REML`

```
m1= lmer(dep ~ 1 + I(x) +  (1+x| id) , data, REML = TRUE) 
m2= lmer(dep ~ 1 + I(x) + I(x^2) + (1+x| id) , data, REML = TRUE)
```

When these 2 models are compared using `anova` function with `refit = FALSE` , the following results are obtained. It seems that the likelihood of full model is less than the likelihood of reduced model .Hence the chi squared value is zero and p value is 1.

```
anova(m1 ,m2 , refit = FALSE)

   Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
m1  6 1009.3 1046.5 -498.63   997.26                        
m2  7 1014.6 1058.1 -500.29  1000.57     0      1          1
```

However if i fit the same models using `ML` instead of `REML`, i  got different results as follows.

```
anova(m1 ,m2 )
refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)

  Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)   
m1  6 989.60 1026.9 -488.80   977.60                            
m2  7 981.14 1024.6 -483.57   967.14 10.463      1   0.001218 **
```

In theory , the likelihood of the full model should be greater than the likelihood of the reduced model. So what may be the reason for this different results using `REML`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the log-likelihoods of linear mixed models with different fixed-effects parts fitted with REML are not comparable. This is because what the REML approach is doing is applying a transformation into you outcome vector `dep` that depends on the chosen fixed effects. Hence, models with different fixed effects result in models with different outcome vectors, and likelihoods of models with different outcomes are not comparable.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Will you be able to provide a reference for this  so that i can read more ?

Comment: I'd recommend books on linear mixed models, e.g., by Verbeke and Molenberghs or Fitzmaurice, Laird and Ware.